# Using scope, How would I limit my Task model to only Tasks that are due today? I'm building a Tasks manager using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-5, date-comparison

Building a Task Manager and need help limiting my Task model to only tasks that are due today
I've tried comparing my task's duedate to Date.now but doesn't seem to be working.

This is my schema

```
  create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "duedate"
    t.boolean "completed"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

This is my Task model.

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  #use scope on Task model to mark overdue Tasks if the present date is greater than duedate.
  scope :overdue, -> { where("duedate < ?", Time.now) }
  scope :due_today, ->{ where("duedate = ?", Date.now) }

  def overdue?
    duedate < Time.now
  end

  def due_today?
    duedate = Date.now
  end
end
```

Comment: Nope.  It doesn't.  I keep getting a NoMethodError (undefined method `now' for Date:Class)

Comment: Yes, Date doesn't have a now method. It has a today method. The first answer to that question shows how to do a "is this timestamp on this day" using a range.

Comment: I've tried that in my controller using.
```
def due_today
    @tasks = Task.all.where(:duedate = Date.now.beginning_of_day..Date.now.end_of_day)
 end
```

Comment: Note that Date.today should be avoided in Rails because of time zones. Use the Date.current Rails extension. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones

Comment: def due_today
    @tasks = Task.all.where(:duedate = Date.current.beginning_of_day..Date.current.end_of_day)
  end

Comment: that didn't work either.

Comment: It's `:duedate =>` or `duedate:`, not `:duedate =`. Like a Hash. And they are class methods on Date. `scope :due_today, ->{ where(due_date: Date.beginning_of_day..Date.end_of_day) }`. See Rails extensions to [Time](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html) and [Date](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html).

Comment: got this when I used that class method

NoMethodError (undefined method `beginning_of_day' for Date:Class)
Did you mean?  beginning_of_week

Comment: This worked! scope :due_today, ->{ where("duedate >= ? AND duedate <= ?", Date.current.beginning_of_day, Date.current.end_of_day) }